# EJB - NullpointerException while injecting bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, wildfly

I am a newbie for EJB and CDI. 
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here:

My code is as below and deployed in a WAR on JBoss WildFly 8:

```
@Stateless(name = "application.listDao")
public class ListDao extends BaseDao {

    @Inject
    private SomeOtherDao someOtherDao;

    // some other methods

}

@Stateless
public abstract class BaseDao {

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public List find( long id ) {

        List list = new ArrayList<>();

        // JPA stuff to perform operations

        return list;
    }

}
```

Now, I am injecting this ListDao in other WAR deployed on same wildfly instance:

```
@RequestScoped
public class ListReport {

    @Inject
    private ListDao listDao;

    public List getReport(long id) {

        // Here I am getting NullPointerException
        List reportList = listDao.find(id);

        return reportList;
    }

}
```

I am getting listDao as null and hence getting NullPointerException.
CDI is enabled by placing empty beans.xml under WEB-INF folder.

Comment: try to inject interface type instead of class type. look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056881/null-pointer-exception-while-ejb-injection

Comment: Use `@PersistenceContext` to inject `EntityManager` instead of `@Inject`.

Comment: Are the war's in the same ear?

Comment: Also, i see no reason to make your DAO EJB-managed. Remove `@Stateless` annotation, that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you're `@Inject`'ing your `EntityManager`, however you haven't provided any evidence that you have a producer for it.  There is no default producer method for `EntityManager`

Comment: ok, I am removing entitymanager stuff, simply ignoring JPA operations.
But still the injected ListDao is getting null

Comment: Maybe you can provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If the other war is not in the same EAR (enterprise archive), this is not possible. Those are two completely separate deployments. The two deployments can't even see the classes of each other because of the classloader isolation. 
You'd need to package the two wars into one ear in this case.

Comment: can you provide me steps to create EAR with 2 existing war ? I did not work on EAR.

Comment: This answer is not correct, you can add Inter deployment dependencies. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly